# Apache Kafka- Understanding the relationship between timeout present as a parameter in the poll() method and fetch.max.wait.ms

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I wanted to understand the relationship between the timeout present in the poll() method and the configuration fetch.max.wait.ms. So , lets say I have the following configuration

```
          fetch.min.bytes= 50
          fetch.max.wait.ms= 400 ms
          timeout on poll method= 200 ms
```

So, consider I call the poll method with the above specified timeout. The Consumer sends a fetch request to the Kafka Broker who is the leader for that partition. The Broker has not got enough bytes to send according to the configuration fetch.min.bytes, so it will wait for maximum of 400 milliseconds to respond for enough data to arrive. But I have configured, the timeout to be 200 ms for the poll method, so does that mean, behind the hood, when the fetch request is sent, it only waits for 200 ms for the server to respond and then terminates the connection?

Is that how it will turn out? In this scenario, would it be safe to say, you would always configure your timeout to be -

```
         timeout >= network latency + fetch.max.wait.ms
```

Also, does Kafka Consumer fetch records proactively? By that I mean, is the consumer busy fetching records behind the hood , when the user code is busy processing the records on the last poll() method call, so that to reduce latency when the next time poll() is called. If yes, how does it maintain this internal buffer? Can we also configure, the maximum size of this internal buffer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Time out on poll` allows you to do asynchronous processing. After subscribing to a set of topics, the consumer will automatically join the group when `poll(long)` is invoked. The poll API is designed to ensure consumer availability.

As long as the consumer continue to call poll, the consumer will stay in the group and continue to receive messages from the partitions it was assigned.

Under the hood, the consumer sends periodic heartbeats to the server. If the consumer crashes or is unable to send heartbeats for a duration of `session.timeout.ms`, then the consumer will be considered dead and its partitions will be reassigned.

But we should be careful that the long value in the `poll(long)` is not too long. This makes the whole process synchronous. You can read the discussion in the below link.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/142

`fetch.max.wait.ms` This will make sure whenever a fetch request is created the server will block the request until the time specified. This usually kicks in if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by `fetch.min.bytes`.

**Point 1**: When there is a fetch request the server blocks your fetch request for 400ms if it does not meet 50bytes.

```
fetch.min.bytes= 50
fetch.max.wait.ms= 400 ms
```

**Point 2**: For every 200ms you consumer sends a heartbeat to avoid rebalance by kafka.

timeout on poll method= 200 ms

When Point 1 happens your consumer is idle but since you did Point 2 the heart beat is sent at every 200ms so rebalance does not occur and you may perform some tasks asynchronously for the next 200ms.

So setting poll() will only make sure that your consumer is not considered dead and fetch.max.wait.ms is to tell the server about how long it need to wait when the fetch request comes. What i mean to say is there is not inherent dependency on the two parameter. poll() is more of the asynchronous way of doing things in your code.

**Timeout is based purely on the poll().**

Comment: Thank you for replying but your answer does not address what I have asked above.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread. The heartbeat is sent in a background thread. They removed the dependency from calling poll.

Comment: The answer was based on your question. In your case timeout is purely based on poll(). You have not specified max.poll.interval.ms this in the question.

Comment: There is a gap, you have not understood, what I wanted to ask, never mind and Thank you.

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: If poll is asynchronous, its not necessary that the variable in which u expect to get back consumer Records, will be populated on the first time u poll?

Comment: A new config, group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms, was introduced. This config specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance. The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms. The default value for this is 3 seconds. In order to avoid this you set the poll(n). With this the consumer advances every n seconds.

Comment: If you dont agree with my answer you can always downvote. So lets not debate on this too much. I am not here to debate.I thought this would be helpful for you or someone who does not put much time in reading the whole documentation.