# fetch.max.wait.ms vs parameter to poll() method

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Before I ask my question, I'd like to point out that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302119/apache-kafka-understanding-the-relationship-between-timeout-present-as-a-parame) but it hasn't been answered so I am asking again. Please do not mark this as duplicate as the previously mentioned question doesn't have any answers.

I have a doubt regarding `fetch.max.wait.ms` and `consumer.poll(<value>)`.
This is what I've found in my research of the above mentioned configs

> The poll() method takes a timeout parameter. This specifies how long it will take poll to return, with or without data
>
> If you set fetch.max.wait.ms to 100 ms and fetch.min.bytes to 1 MB, Kafka will recieve a fetch request from the consumer and will respond with data either when it has 1 MB of data to return or after 100 ms, whichever happens first.

So my question is, what happens when `fetch.max.wait.ms=500`, `consumer.poll(200)` and `fetch.min.bytes= 500` but the broker does not have enough data to return as set by `fetch.min.bytes`?

Comment: Your consumer will keep polling every 200ms. After each poll, it would wait for 500ms. Consumer has specifically asked that it expects at least 500 bytes in response. So broker will not respond until it has 500 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

**fetch.min.bytes**

> This property allows a consumer to specify the minimum amount of data
> that it wants to receive from the broker when fetching records. If a
> broker receives a request for records from a consumer but the new
> records amount to fewer bytes than fetch.min.bytes, the broker will
> wait until more messages are available before sending the records back
> to the consumer.

**fetch.max.wait.ms**

> It Will inform the broker  to wait until it has enough data to send before
> responding to the consumer.
>
> **Example:** If you set fetch.max.wait.ms to 100 ms and fetch.min.bytes to 1 MB,
> Kafka will receive a fetch request from the consumer and will respond
> with data either when it has 1 MB of data to return or after 100 ms,
> whichever happens first.

Above two-parameter control broker while responding message to the consumer.

**poll(timeout)**

> Basically poll() controls how long poll() will block if data is not available in the broker to consume.

the poll is requested on the consumer side to fetch records responded by the Broker. It calls fetchrecords() and if records already available in broker with satisfying the above parameters fetch.min.bytes and fetch.max.wait.ms it will respond immediately else wait till given timeout return empty in case no records available in the broker.

It explained below pollForfetches methods in KafkaConsumer class

```
private Map<TopicPartition, List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>>> pollForFetches(final long timeoutMs) {
        final long startMs = time.milliseconds();
        long pollTimeout = Math.min(coordinator.timeToNextPoll(startMs), timeoutMs);

        // if data is available already, return it immediately
        final Map<TopicPartition, List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>>> records = fetcher.fetchedRecords();
        if (!records.isEmpty()) {
            return records;
        }

        // send any new fetches (won't resend pending fetches)
        fetcher.sendFetches();

        // We do not want to be stuck blocking in the poll if we are missing some positions
        // since the offset lookup may be backing off after a failure

        // NOTE: the use of cachedSubscriptionHashAllFetchPositions means we MUST call
        // updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded before this method.
        if (!cachedSubscriptionHashAllFetchPositions && pollTimeout > retryBackoffMs) {
            pollTimeout = retryBackoffMs;
        }

        client.poll(pollTimeout, startMs, () -> {
            // since a fetch might be completed by the background thread, we need this poll condition
            // to ensure that we do not block unnecessarily in poll()
            return !fetcher.hasCompletedFetches();
        });

        // after the long poll, we should check whether the group needs to rebalance
        // prior to returning data so that the group can stabilize faster
        if (coordinator.rejoinNeededOrPending()) {
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }

        return fetcher.fetchedRecords();
    }
```

if fetch.min.bytes= 500 and fetch.max.wait.ms=500 which means the broker will respond to the consumer when it has 500 bytes of data to return or after 500 ms, whichever happens first.
Consumer side poll will be calling every 200ms calling fetchedRecords to receive any message provided by the broker.

Comment: So let's say this is the timeline:  
T=0: consumer.poll(200);  
T=200: Fetch returns without any data because broker doesn't have 500kB . 
T=201: consumer.poll(200);    
T=401: Fetch returns without any data because broker doesn't have 500kB .  
T=402: consumer.poll(200);  
T=500: (fetch.max.wait.ms) <what happens here>? Will poll return with whatever data broker has even if it is less than 500kB?

Comment: yes if  fetch.max.wait.ms crossed whatever value in broker will get spill out

Answer (score 6):

The configuration that you propose, with `fetch.max.wait.ms > pollDuration` is not a healthy configuration in my opinion, because it leads to strange behavior. I'll try to explain by using an example.

First, let's assume a healthy configuration, where `fetch.max.wait.ms` is less than `pollDuration`.
If you poll and no data is coming through the topic at all, you'll wait until `pollDuration` passes and then `poll()` will return. If you have lots of data in the topic, you'll fetch it and `poll()` will return immediately.

The interesting use-case is if you poll and there is a small amount of data in the topic, less than `fetch.min.bytes`, or there is no data in the topic at all but it arrives while you are polling.
This use-case is as follows:

- Time T0: you start polling
- Time T1: you receive some bytes in the topic, but not enough.

I take it for granted that `T1 < T0 + pollDuration`. Now, the key to understand what happens next is to understand that the "deadline" imposed by `fetch.max.wait.ms` starts kicking at time T0.
Therefore, we have two options:

1. `T1 < T0 + fetch.max.wait.ms` - you'll continue to wait a little more time, and at time `T0 + fetch.max.wait.ms` the poll method will return with the small amount of data. Note that based on my earlier assumpiton, this time is before `T0 + pollDuration`.
2. `T1 > T0 + fetch.max.wait.ms` - in this case Kafka doesn't see a need to wait any longer and the `poll()` method will return at time T1 with the small amount of data.

Now, back to your use-case. Since `fetch.max.wait.ms` is greater than `pollDuration`, you are going to see some strange behavior. Here is one possible use-case:

- Time T0: you start polling, and the topic has a small amount of data.
- Time T1 = T0 + pollDuration: you finish polling without fetching the data.
- Time T2: you start polling again.
- Time T3 = T0 + fetch.max.wait.ms: `poll()` returns and you consume the small amount of data.

Note that if `fetch.max.wait.ms` is sufficiently larger than `pollDuration` then you might see several iterations of polling without fetching any data until finally you'll fetch it. In your example you'll poll twice for a total of 400ms and return empty-handed, and then on the third polling attempt you'll get the data after 100 ms.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documents](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) The server will be block if there is no sufficient data given by `fetch.min.bytes`. So in you case server will wait until `500` ms if there is no enough data

Coming `poll` [public ConsumerRecords poll(long timeout)](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) According to `KafkaConsumer` docs since there is no enough data consumer poll will be empty for every `200` ms until broker having the sufficient data

> timeout - The time, in milliseconds, spent waiting in poll if data is not available in the buffer. If 0, returns immediately with any records that are available currently in the buffer, **else returns empty.** Must not be negative.

**fetch.max.wait.ms**

> The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request **if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes.**

**fetch.min.bytes**

> The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.