# spring cloud stream kafka batch does not consume messages in every 15 minutes even after increasing this config, 'fetch.max.wait.ms'

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, consumer, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to consume message in batch mode in every 15 minutes.
For that I have set these properties,

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.max.poll.records=5000000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.fetch.max.wait.ms=900000
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.fetch.min.bytes=500000000
```

Consuming message works fine when I set this property `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.fetch.max.wait.ms` between `10000` to `30000`, 10seconds or 30 seconds.
But If I increase the `fetch.max.wait.ms` to 1 minutes or more, It doesn't consumes messages even the waiting time is over.

I know the default value is 500ms, but will there be an issue if I increase that??

And How can I get the desired behaviour (consumer to wait for 10-15min before consuming the batch again)??

Can I use `max.poll.interval.ms` for that?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701700/10163782
explains this use case in detail

Comment: @Himanshi if I don't use "fetch.max.wait.ms" then how can I achieve consuming batch in every 15 minutes, any other configurations??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to consume messages in every 15 minutes by setting these properties.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.max.poll.interval.ms=1000000
```

And

setting idleTime between polls using container property.

```
  @Bean
  public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, 
  ?>> customizer() {
    return (container, dest, group) -> 
container.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(idlePollTimeout);

  }
```